# glassfish using virtual directory

Tags: glassfish, hosting, localhost

I'm triing to host some files on my glassfish server.

i found this post explaining how to do this with virtual directories:
http://www.marceble.com/2009/07/virtual-directories-in-glassfish/

but this doesn't work for me
when i surf to: `localhost:8080/media/test.txt`

i get: **HTTP Status 404: The requested resource () is not available.**

screenshot of my glassfish controlpanel:
http://i77.photobucket.com/albums/j74/bertyhell/glassfish_error.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better is [this article](http://harkiran-howtos.blogspot.com/2009/08/map-external-directory-into-glassfish.html).

For GlassFish 3.1.x now it is glassfish-web.xml file inside your application config. If you use something like this:

```
from=/media/* dir=C:/
```

or the same inside glassfish-web.xml file:

```
<property name="alternatedocroot_1" value="from=/media/* dir=C:/"/>
```

**Be sure that you created direcotry on your computer: C:/media**

**"from" must match directory on your computer.**

So then it will be available here:

```
http://{hostName}:{portNumber}/myapp/media/*
```